# Looking for word problem books

Tags: book-recommendation, word-problem

I am looking for Grade 6 - 12 math books with word problems least 1/4 page long or more. Long time ago I once saw one such word problem practice book for grades 6 - 8, but I can't remember the title or publisher. Any recommendations?

Comment: Sam Loyd's book(s) (revised by Martin Gardner). Though old fashioned, many problems are captivating and illustrations are funny.

Comment: *Maybe* Manhattan Prep's [**Word Translations GMAT Strategy Guide**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0981853374) would be useful?